# animated journey using mapkit polyline

Tags: ios, animation, mapkit, android-mapview, polyline

Good morning,
I have an app with a search list showing the trips.
After selectina one of it I need to show the trip viewing on the map a little car following all coordinates related for every GPS points I have in my trip's database for that trip.
Basically my app have three view the login page, the search page and the mapview.
In the search page I need also to include a filter by the city name (start or end) and the trip date range.
About the animation of the trip it's possible to include a bar at the bottom of map view to have play ,forward anda back buttons like a record player ?

Thank's in advance and sorry for my english.

Brunix

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  For similar examples, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504822/animate-a-visual-element-along-an-arc-in-mapkit/22506771#22506771, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861403/latitude-and-longitude-points-from-mkpolyline/21865454#21865454, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918453/trying-to-simulate-a-route-in-mapview, etc.  The examples automatically iterate through the coordinates on a timer but you can also make it user-controlled with forward/back buttons.

Comment: Thank'you for answer. I didn't perform a good search before writing my question :-)

Comment: Dear Anna, 
I follow your answer in the third example.
Finally I have my pin going through the route.
If is possible can you help me in the following questions ?
First of all how can I change the pin image with a png file ow my own.
Second questions it's possible to leave an image (ex. a little black circle) for every point ?
Finally it's possible to trace a line between the points of the route ?
Remember thath I follow your third example (the customAnnotation one).
Thank's in advance every suggest will be very useful
Brunix